# Sending users messages - The right way

Tags: facebook, send, message

we would like to let the logged user in our web site invite his friends to participate in some scenario, IIRC the options we have are:

Keep in mind, we MUST know which users the message/notification sent to in order to interact back with the selection.

1) Raise a request dialog, with the multi friend selector, but unfortunately the 'message' field in the 'apprequest' dialog is only displayed in the app center and is not visible in the top bar notifications. which is very important for us.

2) Send a personal message, but this has no friend selector, so we raise the 'send' dialog but the selected recipients by user are not being recieved in the callback (only status is recieved back)

This question was asked here:
[When a Facebook user sends the Send dialog within an application, can the application track the recipients?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9298214/when-a-facebook-user-sends-the-send-dialog-within-an-application-can-the-applic)

We thought maybe to raise our own dialog for friend selection, and then popup the 'send dialog' with a pre-defined recipients but the user still can change the recipient in the send dialog (there's no way to freeze the selected recipients)

So what is the solution for this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to go with app notifications as it's the best option for the current restrictions.